# Linux: How to build a single command with parameters depending on current time range

Tags: linux, shell

I want to create a command which appends a specific parameter **only** when the current time is between midnight and 6am.

Example pseudo-code:

```
mvn clean verify <#if isBetweenMidnightAnd6AM> -Dfindbugs.skip=false</#if>
```

Is it possible to build this in a single command line or do I need a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost certainly better off with a shell script here. You could do it with a very, very ugly line like this: (note: not debuged/tested)

```
mvn clean verify $( if [ ($(date +%H) -ge 0) && ($(date +%H) -le 6) ];then echo  "-Dfindbugs.skip=false";fi;)
```

The script would be a lot easier to look at anyway. It would look something like:

```
if [ ($(date +%H) -ge 0) && ($(date +%H) -le 6) ]
then
  mvn clean verify -Dfindbugs.skip=false
else
  mvn clean verify $Your_other_opts
fi
```

Additionally, with the script you would be able to put some better debug, and verification in to make sure it ran right.

That said, this seems to be something that wouldn't be run manually, so you could go really simple and do a cron job like:

```
0 0-6 * * * mvn clean verify -Dfindbugs.skip=false
```

Which will run the command at the top of the hours 0 (midnight) - 6 (6 AM).

Comment: Thanks. I needed to add one more square bracket. Here is the working 1-liner:  mvn clean verify $( if [[ ($(date +%H) -ge 0) && ($(date +%H) -le 6) ]];then echo "-Dfindbugs.skip=false"; fi; )